# Call functions from iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, iframe

I am uploading files using a hidden iframe as a target...from inside this iframe I want to run a function that's on my main page.

In my target `iframe.php` I have

```
<script>

upload_completed(<?php echo $numerolinha ?>); 
    </script>
```

but I get from firebug:

```
ReferenceError: loading_linha_21 is not defined
parent.upload_completed();</script>
```

If I run `upload_completed(loading_linha_21);` on my main page it runs ok so I'm guessing the command to run the function on the parent page isn't working... help!

I also tried :

```
window.top.upload_completed(<?php echo $numerolinha ?>); 

window.upload_completed(<?php echo $numerolinha ?>);
```

my functions :

```
 <script >
 function upload_started(id){

  $(id).css("display","block");
 }
 function upload_completed(id){
 $(id).css("display","none");
 }


 </script>
```

Comment: So `loading_linha_21` is the name of a JS variable? Or is it supposed to be a string (in which case your output would be missing quotes)?

Comment: No, `$numerolinha` is your PHP variable. But when you output that value as part of some JS code, what is is supposed to be _in that context_? Do you have a JS variable named `loading_linha_21`, or is that supposed to be a string value?

Comment: Its a js variable but i sokved this other way tks 4 the help

Comment: And that variable is in the parent document as well? Then of course you have to address the parent first – same as you do with your function call: `parent.upload_completed(parent.loading_linha_21)`

Comment: maybe that was the problem tks i used other way to upload the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guess i can give you is that the jQuery function requires the id to be `#name_of_id`, so when you call the function from the iframe like so:

```
parent.upload_completed('#<?php echo $numerolinha ?>');
```

or you can change your function to do this:

```
function upload_started(id){
    $( '#' + id).css("display","block");
}

function upload_completed( id ) {
    $( '#' + id ).css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: My var allready as the # but tks 4 the tip vote up for the efort :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a `'` inside function like below :

```
<script>
upload_completed('<?php echo $numerolinha ?>'); 
</script>
```

Comment: still didnt work , i also tried parent.upload_completed('<?php echo $numerolinha ?>');  and window.parent.upload_completed('<?php echo $numerolinha ?>'); but no joy

Comment: @I-amSam Please add your functions

Comment: ok i edited my question with the functions..but they work well , if i run the functions as they read on html (in firebug) they work...they just dont work on the parent page